# Dataflow of battery's information from kernel to application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, battery

I'm newbie in linux and I have a question:
**Dataflow of battery's imformation from kernel to application?**

I write a driver for my Ic gas gauge bq27541 and it run suscess. But I want know why and how application can take imformation from my baterry.

I had read some book about sysfs, system call, netlink socket, udev..but I don't know how to answer my question.

Comment: Firstly I would recommended rephrasing your entire post, as per stackoverflow standards, if you want people to help you out.

Comment: *bq27541* will use either i2c or one wire.  See: [Sysfs-class-power](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-power) and other ideas for providing the information to user space.  All of your ideas are possible ways to provide the information.  If you want a standard, then look through the Linux documentation directory.